# Compatibility with RTL installations

Tags: plugins, dashboard

I want develop a plugin that add boxes and menus in WordPress backed.

What I have to keep in mind to make it **compatible with WordPress RTL** installations?

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`is_rtl()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_rtl) to check if the user is setup for RTL or not, then you would just need to register and enqueue the RTL styles instead of the LTR styles.

Comment: Thanks, when you mention RTL styles you mean the possible CSS styles I add in my plugin or you are referring to some other required CSS?

If my plugin doesn't add any CSS because use WordPress default ones, I don't need to worry about compatibility with RTL installation?

Comment: You will need to add the stylesheets, at the very least changing the direction of the text. Read the documentation that I linked in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I had already seen the link about is_rtl() function, but my question was: if I need to use it. You already reply this in last comment, thanks!